# How to store an IStream to a file via C#?

Tags: c#, istream

I'm working with a 3rd party component that returns an IStream object (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream).  I need to take the data in that IStream and write it to a file.  I've managed to get that done, but I'm not really happy with the code.

With "strm" being my IStream, here's my test code...

```
// access the structure containing statistical info about the stream
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG stat;
strm.Stat(out stat, 0);
System.IntPtr myPtr = (IntPtr)0;

// get the "cbSize" member from the stat structure
// this is the size (in bytes) of our stream.
int strmSize = (int)stat.cbSize; // *** DANGEROUS *** (long to int cast)
byte[] strmInfo = new byte[strmSize];
strm.Read(strmInfo, strmSize, myPtr);

string outFile = @"c:\test.db3";
File.WriteAllBytes(outFile, strmInfo);
```

At the very least, I don't like the long to int cast as commented above, but I wonder if there's not a better way to get the original stream length than the above?  I'm somewhat new to C#, so thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that cast, as you can read data from `IStream` source in chunks.

```
// ...
System.IntPtr myPtr = (IntPtr)-1;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\test.db3", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while (myPtr.ToInt32() > 0)
    {
        strm.Read(buffer, buffer.Length, myPtr);
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, myPtr.ToInt32());
    }
}
```

This way (if works) is more memory efficient, as it just uses a small memory block to transfer data between that streams.

Comment: Rubens - thanks for the above sample code.  It definitely clarifies some things for me.  Unfortunately, I haven't been in a position to test this since I posted it, and won't be for a bit longer.  At that time, I'll either accept this answer, or post for more clarification if needed.

Comment: myPtr should be initialized to something above 0 as it will never enter the while loop if the init value is -1.

Comment: You need to actually allocate some memory for that pointer, not just throw a value into it, otherwise `myPtr` isn't going to contain anything of use. And you have to read the value out; `myPtr.ToInt32()` isn't doing what you think. Also, the number of bytes read is a `long`, so you'll need to read an `Int64` value and cast it.

Answer (score 1):

System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream is a wrapper for ISequentialStream.

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380011(VS.85).aspx

> The actual number of bytes read can be
>   less than the number of bytes
>   requested if an error occurs or if the
>   end of the stream is reached during
>   the read operation. The number of
>   bytes returned should always be
>   compared to the number of bytes
>   requested. If the number of bytes
>   returned is less than the number of
>   bytes requested, it usually means the
>   Read method attempted to read past the
>   end of the stream.

This documentation says, that you can loop and read as long as pcbRead is less then cb.